# Pointer inside an object which points to the object itself

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and I am very confused about pointers. I want to create a class which has a pointer to an array of pointers (mClass).
Pointers inside the array should point to another class (Handle) which itself has another pointer that should point to itself (ptr).

I get a compile error:

```
invalid use of non-static data member
'Myclass<int>::mClass' ptr(&mClass[i]){}
```

Below is the header I want to compile. How can I solve this issue? How can I create a pointer inside an object which points to the object itself?

```
template<typename T>
class Myclass
{    
    private:
       const unsigned mCapacity;
       unsigned mSize;
       class Handle;
       Handle **mClass;

       class Handle
       {
           friend Myclass;
           private:
               unsigned index;
               T mVal;
               Handle *ptr;

           public:
               Handle(unsigned i, T t) : index(i),
                                         mVal(t),
                                         ptr(&mClass[i]){} //here I want to get the address of  the pointer mClass.   
    public:
        Myclass(unsigned capacity) : mCapacity(capacity),
                                     mSize(0),
                                     mClass(new Handle*[capacity])
};
```

Comment: You need to have some reference to a specific instance of `Myclass<T>` in your `Handle` constructor, otherwise the compiler cannot know which `mClass` you are trying to refer to

Comment: I tried to solve that issue by giving the array index such as mClass[i]. So I thought I was refering to the i^th mClass. What else should I refer to?

Comment: `mClass` ***itself*** is a member of some `Myclass<T>`. You need a pointer to ***one of those***, whose `mClass` you wish to store a pointer to.

Comment: @pointerToMe You seem to think that the inner class `Handle` has some sort of special access to the outer class `Myclass<T>`. That is true in Java, it's not true in C++. Imagine `Handle` moved out of `MyClass<T>` how would it then know which `mClass` you are referring to? Well that's the same situation you are facing now. The `Handle` constructor needs a reference to an instance of `Myclass<T>` passed as a parameter (at least something like that).